# Showing links inwards in a layout-circle with NetLogo

Tags: layout, netlogo

I'd like to know if there's a way to direct the graphical output of links in a `circle-layout` inside the circle. I have written the following procedure

```
to setup
ca
create-turtles 100
layout-circle (sort turtles) max-pxcor - 1
  ask turtles [(create-links-with n-of (random 3) other turtles) ]
end
```

Which gives the result in the image below. Does anybody know of a way to have all links show within the circle instead of some springing outwards?

[image: turtle-linksin a circle-layout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the world to be a torus, make it a box (by unticking the two wrap boxes in Interface > Settings). Links will automatically show within the circle (or just on its perimeter), because that is where the new shortest distance between turtles is now.